# Why is there a light blue border around my Power BI Publish to Web iframe?

Tags: powerbi

Example here: http://parrystats.com/cfb/viz

When you click within the iframe, an ugly light blue border appears. The iframe is the same size as the page size in Desktop: 1280 x 4500 pixels. All other page settings are default. The theme is default as well.

I've set iframe { border: 0 } in my CSS. I've also set frameborder="0", while also trying frameBorder="0"

Can anyone shed some light on this border?

Comment: Generally, it shows to indicate the border of the report screen... By the way, I can't able to access the link, please recheck and upload it once again..

Comment: @WannaCoffee sorry about the link - i moved it to http://parrystats.com

Answer (score 0):

I think i know what you mean, and it is caused by the CSS of `reportembed.bundle.min.css:17287`:

```
.embedWrapper:focus .canvasFlexBox .displayAreaContainer .displayArea {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #51caee !important;
    outline: 1px solid #51caee !important;
}
```

This is inside the iframe and therefore it can't be changed by a single CSS line.

There is a post about how to change style inside an iframe, but it seems that this won't work with PowerBI Embedded Report: [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Comment: I will give this a try; by the way, the correct link is now: http://parrystats.com

Comment: unfortunately, ths did not work. I set both the box-shadow and outline to 0 and it still shows the border.